# Is this in-scope for Programmers: Imitating Exchange AuthZ in my own app

Tags: discussion

I haven't had much progress with my architecture question on SO.  Is it a good fit for Programmers?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/9271961/328397

Comment: If you go ahead and flag it for moderation attention, make sure you add a link to this meta question so the SO mods know that we want the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very first line in the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. If you have a question about…
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts

So I'd say yes.

If you want it migrating flag it for a Stack Overflow moderator to migrate.

Comment: Thanks; I was a early user of Programmers.SE but the ontopic nature changed since then (many of my posts were flagged OT).  Thanks for the verification.